# how to separate the the Flutter dropdown items and preview?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

[image]

[image]

I have a dropdown and these are the codes :

```
 return Center(
          child: DropdownButton<ActivityPriority>(
            value: widget.selectedValue != null
                ? dropdownItemsPortrait[checkValueIndex()].value
                : null,
            hint: Text(S.of(context).select),
            items: dropdownItemsPortrait,
            underline: Container(),
            onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = v;
                widget.onSelection(v);
              });
            },
          ),
        );
```

and the items are fetch like this :

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem> get dropdownItemsPortrait {
List<DropdownMenuItem<ActivityPriority>> menuItemsPortrait = widget.mList
    .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(child: SizedBox(width: 100.0 ,child: Text("statustuisssssss", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, )), value: e))
    .toList();
return menuItemsPortrait;
}
```

the problem is that when click on the button the items are shown with truncate , but I only want to show the truncate in the preview of it beside of the button

any idea please?

Comment: can you include an image indicating error

Comment: I added the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectedItemBuilder`.

```dart
return DropdownButton(
  selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return list.map<Widget>((String item) {
      return Text(
        item //youData
      );
    }).toList();
  },
```