# how to remove the space between two items of row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

[image]I have a row widget and 2 **dropdowns** as its children . I commented the value of the second one but the space is still there , how can I remove that *space* between them ?

```
        return Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              DropdownButton<ActivityPriority>(
                value: widget.selectedValue != null
                    ? dropdownItemsLandscape[checkValueIndex()].value
                    : null,
                hint: Text(S.of(context).select),
                items: dropdownItemsPortrait,
                iconSize: 0.0,
                underline: Container(),
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = v;
                    widget.onSelection(v);
                  });
                },
              ),
              DropdownButton<ActivityPriority>(
                // value: widget.selectedValue != null
                //     ? dropdownItemsLandscape[checkValueIndex()].value
                //     : null,
                // hint: Text(S.of(context).select),
                items: dropdownItemsLandscape,
                underline: Container(),
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = v;
                    widget.onSelection(v);
                  });
                },
              ),                ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Can you provide a better image? And in that image mark the space you want to have removed?

Comment: thanks for answer . the space between 'first' and the dropdown icon , I want to place 'first' near the icon

Comment: The size of the `DropdownButton` will adapt to the widest child of the `DropdownMenuItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behnam jan, as I found out from your question, to remove space between your dropDown buttons you can wrap your second dropDown button with `Expanded` bro:

```
return Center(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      DropdownButton<ActivityPriority>(
        value: widget.selectedValue != null
            ? dropdownItemsLandscape[checkValueIndex()].value
            : null,
        hint: Text(S.of(context).select),
        items: dropdownItemsPortrait,
        iconSize: 0.0,
        underline: Container(),
        onChanged: (v) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = v;
            widget.onSelection(v);
          });
        },
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: DropdownButton<ActivityPriority>(
          // value: widget.selectedValue != null
          //     ? dropdownItemsLandscape[checkValueIndex()].value
          //     : null,
          // hint: Text(S.of(context).select),
          items: dropdownItemsLandscape,
          underline: Container(),
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = v;
              widget.onSelection(v);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

happy coding...

Comment: Mamnoon brother , if you have a free time can you please take a look at this one too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75856641/how-to-separate-the-the-flutter-dropdown-items-and-preview

Comment: I saw your another question bro, please let me know I could help you or not, how about this question